# Automatically close magnific Popup iframe after ajax request result

Tags: jquery, ajax, iframe, magnific-popup

**Here is my code that i am trying**

```
$.post("/Users/AjaxLoginBox", function(data) {
parent.$('#fix_header_wrap').find('#Login_Box').html(data);
//i have tried
parent.$('#Login_Box').find("#timeshare_pulse").trigger("click");
//also
parent.$.magnificPopup.close();
//also
$.magnificPopup.close();
}, "html");
```

i have tried all but couldn't found any solution some time it gives me error that "$.magnificPopup is undefined".
Please somebody help me out.Thanks

Comment: make sure you have included js file for `magnificpopup`

Comment: i have login box in magnific popup and its successfully let me login but after login i have to manually close the popup but i don't want to manually close magnific popup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried this and my problem get solved

```
parent.$('.mfp-close').trigger("click");
```

Comment: Thanks @SumithHarshan